# Перепишите код, чтобы он занимал меньше строк (сейчас - 20 строк)

Tags: python, функции, числовые-последовательности

Ваша задача упростить мою программу, но сохранить функционал

Согласно *гипотезе Коллатца*, любое число можно перевести в такую последовательность цифр, которая всегда заканчивается единицей. Эту последовательность называют *простейшей из неразрешённых проблем математики*, потому что это гипотеза так и не была доказана. Последовательность словами описывается очень просто: есть функция, в которую мы передаём любое число. Если число чётное, тогда делим его на 2 ( т.е. `число / 2` ). Если нечётное - тогда мы это число умножаем на 3 + 1 ( т.е. `число * 3 + 1` ). Значение, которое нам вернула функция мы опять подставляем в эту функцию ( такая своеобразная рекурсия )

```
    def collatz( number ) :
      if number % 2 == 0 : # чётное
        result = number // 2
      if number % 2 == 1 : # нечётное
        result = 3 * number + 1
      print( result )
      return result
    
    error = True
    while error :
      error = True
      try :
        num = int( input( 'Введите число больше нуля: ' ) )
        if num > 0 :
          error = False
      except :
        error = True
    
    firstTime = True
    while num != 1 or firstTime :
      firstTime = False
      num = collatz( num )
    
    # если number - чётное, тогда это число надо разделить на 2 без остатка
```

Comment: По состоянию на 2020 год гипотеза была проверена компьютером для всех начальных значений до ```2 ** 68 × 2,95 × 10 ** 20```. Все проверенные до сих пор начальные значения в конечном итоге заканчиваются повторяющимся циклом ( 4 2 1 ) периода 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У меня без `def`, с `while`:

```
while True:
    n=int(input("Введите любое число больше нуля  --> "))
    if n > 0:
        break
while True:
    if n == 1:
        print("Конец! Получилось число 1!")
        break
    if n%2==0:
        n=int(n/2)
        print(n)
    else:
        n=n*3+1
        print(n)
```

Итого - 14 строк!

Comment: в первоначальном варианте была защита от ввода `ansddsd` вместо числа ;-)

Comment: @ПИТОНИСТ-версия-3-8 вы забыли отступ после первого while

Comment: Да, просто плохо скопировалось)

Comment: ваш код сворачивается до 8 строк кстати - `while True:
    n=int(input("Введите любое число больше нуля  --> "))
    if n > 0:
        while n > 1:
            n = (n * 3 + 1) if n % 2 else (n // 2)
            print(n)
        break
print("Конец! Получилось число 1!")`

Comment: @ПИТОНИСТверсия3-8 я кстати в качестве чисел пробовал вводить очень большие типа 22222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222 и больше и все они сворачиваются в единицу. Это чудо

Comment: Да, сам пробовал, круто)

Answer (score 3):

> Ваша задача упростить мою программу, но сохранить функционал

а ваша задача научиться правильно формулировать вопрос :) или с таким вопросом идти на удаление темы как учебного задания

вариант 1:

```
def collatz(number):
    result = (number // 2) if number % 2 == 0 else (3 * number + 1)
    print(result)
    if result != 1:
        collatz(result)


num = 0

while num <= 0:
    try:
        num = int(input('Введите число больше нуля: '))
    except:
        num = 0

collatz(num)
```

функцию можно переделать в таком виде, чтобы сразу обрабатывать число 1 и выводить всю комбинацию, начиная с первого числа

```
def collatz(number):
    print(number)
    if number != 1:
        result = (number // 2) if number % 2 == 0 else (3 * number + 1)
        collatz(result)
```

вот вариант без `print` внутри функции, т.е. формирование списка и вывод списка:

```
def collatz(number):
    res = [number]
    if number != 1:
        result = (number // 2) if number % 2 == 0 else (3 * number + 1)
        res += collatz(result)
    return res

num = 0

while num <= 0:
    try:
        num = int(input('Введите число больше нуля: '))
    except:
        num = 0

print(*collatz(num), sep='\n')
```

Ну и решение в 1 строчку:

```
def collatz(number):
    return [number] + ([] if number == 1 else (collatz((number // 2) if number % 2 == 0 else (3 * number + 1))))

num = 0

while num <= 0:
    try:
        num = int(input('Введите число больше нуля: '))
    except:
        num = 0

print(*collatz(num), sep='\n')
```

Еще более короткий вариант функции:

```
def collatz(value):
    return [value] + ([] if value == 1 else (collatz((3 * value + 1) if value % 2 else (value // 2))))
```

Итак, если не требуется проверки на неверный ввод данных, то код можно свернуть в следующий вид:

```
def collatz(i):
    return [i] + ([] if i <= 1 else (collatz((3 * i + 1) if i % 2 else (i // 2))))

print(*collatz(int(input('Введите число больше нуля: '))), sep='\n')
```

итого код - 3 строчки :)

Comment: давайте сформулируем ) мне просто понравилась сама гипотеза. Мне показалось нечестно заставлять людей её реализовывать с нуля

Comment: держите решение задачи в 1 строчку

Comment: если вы не против, давайте отдадим победу Питонису, ну вы то однозначно вне конкурса )

Comment: Спасибо большое)